# Use method of moments to estimate $r$ and $\theta$ from a Negative Binomial sample

Tags: statistics

The R code below generates a random sample of size $n = 10$ from a negative-binomial$(r, \theta)$ distribution and stores the sample in $x$. I have deleted the values of $r$ and $\theta$. Use the method of moments to estimate the values of $r$ and $\theta$. You may use information in the $R$ code below.

Note: the probability mass function of negbin($r, \theta$) is given by $$P(x) = {r-1+x\choose x} \theta^r(1-\theta)^x, x = 0,1,2,\dots$$

[image]

which is $n = 10, r = deleted, \theta = deleted$

$x$ ~ $negbin(n = size, r, \theta)$

and $x_i$ stores those values $5, 14, 11, 8, 13, 3, 12,7,4,7$

$m1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 8.9$

$sum(x^2)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 = 997$

---

attempt

$sum(x^2)/n$ is  $m_2$

so

$m_2 = 997/10 = 99.7$

not sure what to do now

Comment: Do you know what the first and second moments of a negative binomial are in terms of $r$ and $\theta$? I.e. the mean  and the sum of the variance and the square of the mean?

Comment: You have $E(X)=(1-\theta)r/\theta$ and $V(X)=(1-\theta)r/\theta^2.$ For MME, set $\bar X=(1-\theta)r/\theta$ and $S^2=(1-\theta)r/\theta^2.$ Then solve for $\theta$ and $r$ in terms of $\bar X$ and $S^2.$ // Notice that the resulting MME for $r$ need not be an integer.// If you consult alternate sources, be sure you have the right parameterization; at least 4 different ones are in common use.// I'm a huge fan of demonstrating theoretical facts about probability distributions using R, but I don't see the relevance of your R program to the current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment continued.**

Because you tried a demo in R, I will show you my attempt.

First set parameters $r = 5$ (successes awaited) and $\theta = 0.2$
(success probability).  Thus the expected number failures observed
when waiting for $r$ successes is $X$ with $E(X) = 20$ and $Var(X) = 100.$

```
r = 5;  th = 0.2
mu = (1-th)*r/th;  mu  
[1] 20
vr = (1-th)*r/th^2; vr
[1] 100
```

Now I simulate $m = 10^6$ realizations of $X$ and find the 
mean and variance of this huge sample

```
set.seed(411);  m = 10^6  # seed for reproducibility
x = rnbinom(m, r, th)
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 20.03666       # aprx E(X)
[1] 100.3452       # aprx Var(X)
```

With these results, our MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat \theta = \bar X/S^2 = 0.1997 \approx \theta = 0.2.$  I will leave the MLE of $r$ to you.

```
mean(x)/var(x)
[1] 0.1996773      # MLE of success probability, close to 0.2
```